# Meaning of end of political life

Tags: meaning, phrases, literature

I am reading the Nicomachean Ethics of Aristotle. Now I am going through book 1 section 5 and here is the one-sentence of section 5.

*A consideration of the prominent types of life shows that people of superior refinement and of active disposition identify happiness with honour, for this is, roughly speaking, the end of the political life.*

I am having difficulty to understand the last term **the end of the political life**.

I would appreciate your help to make me understand.

Thanks.

Comment: An ***end*** is a goal.

Comment: The [**end³**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/end) – The goal or desired result.

Comment: In today's world, one might interpret this to mean that the identification of happiness with honor spells the literal end of one's political life. That is, one cannot identify happiness with honor and continue to be a politician. Perhaps Aristotle was more right than he knew.

Comment: @RichardKayser -  No, I don’t think that’s what it means.

Comment: @Jim I know. Just commenting on the state of our politics today, on what, if anything, lies at the intersection of honor and politics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance and context, **end** = the [final] goal; the purpose.

OED

> **14. a. An intended result of an action; an aim, purpose.** (Cf. Latin finis.)
>
> 1875   B. Jowett tr. Plato Dialogues (ed. 2) V. 323   *They may fairly use a little violence in order to accomplish their end.*
>
> **b. In phrases, for or to this (that, what, which) end, to no end. Also in conjunctional phrase, to the end (that); formerly also, †to the end to (with infinitive).Now somewhat archaic or rhetorical; the ordinary phrase is in order (that or to).**
>
> 1849   T. B. Macaulay Hist. Eng. I. 170   *For these ends, and for these ends alone, he wished to obtain arbitrary power.*
>
> **15. A final cause; the object for which a thing exists; the purpose for which it is designed or instituted.**
>
> 1776   E. Gibbon Decline & Fall I. xxiv. 702   *I have considered the happiness of the people as the end of government.*
>
> 1869   J. Ruskin Queen of Air §60   *The flower is the end or proper object of the seed.*

Comment: thank you. `the political life` made more confusing at first.